# Proving that the interval $(0,1)$ is uncountable

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

I'm trying to show that the interval $(0,1)$ is uncountable and I want to verify that my proof is correct

My solution:

Suppose by way of contradiction that $(0, 1)$ is countable. Then we can create a one-to-one correspondence between $\mathbb{N}$ and $(0,1)$.

$1 \rightarrow 0.a_{0,0}$ $a_{0,1}$ $a_{0,2}$ $a_{0,3} \dots$

$2 \rightarrow 0.a_{1,0}$ $a_{1,1}$ $a_{1,2}$ $a_{1,3} \dots$

$3 \rightarrow 0.a_{2,0}$ $a_{2,1}$ $a_{2,2}$ $a_{2,3} \dots$

$4 \rightarrow 0.a_{3,0}$ $a_{3,1}$ $a_{3,2}$ $a_{3,3} \dots$

$\dots$

Create a number of the form $0.b_0 $ $b_1$ $b_2$ $b_3 \dots$ in the following way. Define $b_i = 1$ if $a_{i, i} \neq 1$ and define $b_i = 2$ if $a_{i, i} = 1$.

Note, since decimal representations are not necessarily unique ( i.e $.599999 = .600000$), choose the representation consisting of infinitely many zeros instead of infinitely many nines.

Creating our number $0.b_0 $ $b_1$ $b_2$ $b_3 \dots$ in this way gives us a number that is not in the above list of decimals in one-to-one correspondence with $\mathbb{N}$, but is in $(0,1)$. This is a contradiction. Thus showing that $(0,1)$ is uncountable.

Is there anything I need to add or is there any way that I can make my proof clearer? Thank you.

Comment: One way to side-step the non-uniqueness of  representations is to work in base $10$ and let $b_n=4$ if $a_{n,n}\ne 4,$ and $b_n=5$ if $a_{n,n}=4.$ But your work is OK.  References: Georg Cantor,... & Diagonalization Method

Answer (score 5):

To me it is fine.

I know a similar method, which is clearer to me. Suppose $(0,1)$ is countable, and create a one-to-one list as you have done. Now, choose the number $0,b_0b_1b_2...$ so that $b_0\neq a_{0,0}$, $b_1\neq a_{1,1}$, and in general, $b_i\neq a_{i,i}$. That number cannot be in the list.

Comment: Isn't this exactly what OP has done?

Comment: Yes, essentially.

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, you have to prove that

- such a number exists in $\Bbb R$ (it is defined by a Cauchy sequence) and
- it is not equal to any of the other numbers (show that difference $>\epsilon$)

Other than that, your proof is fine.

Answer (score -5):

Let's assume that the interval (0, 1) is countable.
As the interval is countable, we will be able to list all the elements of this set.
Or to say A can be expressed as {a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6 ..... }.
where a1 < a2 < a3 < a4 and so on.
As a1 is not equal to a2, we can say that there exists at least a real number between a1 and a2, which is contradictory as we have already listed all the elements of A.
And hence A is an uncountable set.

Comment: Are you assuming that $a_1 < a_2 < a_3 < \cdots$? How do you conclude that such an ordering can be produced? If not, why is the existence of a number between $a_1$ and $a_2$ a contradiction?

Comment: Yes, there is such an order. The existence of a number between a1 and a2 is a contradiction because initially, I have assumed that the set (0, 1) or A is countable and as it is countable, it will be possible to list all the items of this set or A = {a1, a2, a3, ....}. But later on, I go on to prove that a real number is missing as a real exist between a1 and a2, which is contradictory.

Comment: The existence of an enumeration does not guarantee that the enumeration is *in order* by $<$. For example, $\mathbb{Q} \cap (0, 1)$ *is* countable. Can you produce an *ordered* enumeration of this set? If so, what is $a_1$? What is $a_2$?