# Attempt at counting (0,1)

Tags: real-analysis, cardinals, fake-proofs

I'm having trouble seeing where this goes wrong.

> I count by order of magnitude: $0.1,0.2,0.3 ... 0.9$. Then I go back and do $0.11,0.12,..,0.19$, and $0.21,0.22,..,0.29$, all the way to  $0.91,0.92,..,0.99$ then go down an order of magnitude again $0.101, 0.102$ and so on. Like this I count all numbers on (0,1)

I suspect I miss infinite decimal expansions, but it isn't a very satisfying reason alone. For example if I argued: If I miss decimal expansions, it doesn't work because I miss some reals. If I do hit decimal expansions e.g $0.33333... = \frac{1}{3}$, then I counted $0.1999...=0.2$ twice, so our mapping isn't 1-1.

Is this reasoning sufficient?

PS I know (0,1) is uncountable, please don't mark this as a duplicate of other questions proving that it is uncountable, especially if they don't have accepted answers...

Comment: you miss all irrational numbers

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proving that the interval $(0,1)$ is uncountable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2121350/proving-that-the-interval-0-1-is-uncountable)

Comment: @JohnNash No. I know (0,1) is uncountable. I used the tag fake proofs.

Comment: @username2212 what is your mapping from $\Bbb{N}$ to $(0,1)$?

Comment: {0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,...,0.11,0.12,0.13,..,0.21,0.22,..,0.91,0.92..0.99,0.101 and so on ...}

Comment: Every irrational is located at infinity, and there are an infinite number of irrational. Your method doesn't distinguish between them.

Comment: When do you hit $0.05$ ?